# Blocked Process Report -two updates causing a long block

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking

I have a .NET application which is getting SQL update timeouts and I believe that some sort of blocking/locking is taking place which is causing this. I have ran a blocking process report on the database and found some potential culprits: 17 seconds worth of blocking.

Below is such log ( there are many similar ):

```
<blocked-process-report>
 <blocked-process>
  <process id="process308898748" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 99:774293818:0 " waittime="17146" ownerId="66317995993" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-06-15T12:59:05.817" XDES="0x3bc9cd970" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="7" kpid="11204" status="suspended" spid="161" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-06-15T12:59:05.817" lastbatchcompleted="2015-06-15T12:59:05.817" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WORKFLOWG10" hostpid="6832" loginname="WorkflowStateUpdaterSP" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="66317995993" currentdb="99" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="1" stmtstart="16" sqlhandle="0x02000000cb1bb914fe051a308bd33cb2b873948749c2a96d"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0200000075c8f5236facd1f18bca0258f9d4babad99091d6"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
UPDATE [ScheduDB].[dbo].[SP_ScheduleEvent] set DateLastProcessed = GETDATE() where ScheduleEventID = 3111573   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocked-process>
 <blocking-process>
  <process status="suspended" waitresource="OBJECT: 99:774293818:0 " waittime="17182" spid="278" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-06-15T12:59:05.780" lastbatchcompleted="2015-06-15T12:59:05.780" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WORKFLOWG12" hostpid="9944" loginname="WorkflowStateUpdaterSP" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="66317995589" currentdb="99" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="1" stmtstart="16" sqlhandle="0x02000000cb1bb914fe051a308bd33cb2b873948749c2a96d"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0200000001c6452aee248fd8f9f2be0e27c7038cfa4e334f"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
UPDATE [ScheduDB].[dbo].[SP_ScheduleEvent] set DateLastProcessed = GETDATE() where ScheduleEventID = 3807096   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocking-process>
</blocked-process-report>
```

As you can see it appears that two updates are blocking each other and I'm struggling to see why.

Here are the database specifics that might help you help me:

```
TABLE: SP_ScheduleEvent
------
|ScheduleEventID| PK| bigint| not null|
...
|DateLastProcessed| | datetime| not null|
...

INDEX:
ScheduleEventID, "use page locks when accessing the index is set to" FALSE ( row locks is on )
```

Typically I have many processes running on different machines that would trigger this UPDATE, I run the update from a DBDataContext within a .NET application ( Linq to SQL) like so:

```
string sqlUpdateString = "UPDATE [ScheduDB].[dbo].[SP_ScheduleEvent] set DateLastProcessed = GETDATE() where ScheduleEventID = " + scheduleEvent.ScheduleEventID;
db.ExecuteCommand(sqlUpdateString);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Blocked process report (which you have) can be a little confusing at first. There are a few important sections

**Blocking-Process**
This is the process(SP, query etc) that is causing the blocking. The process is using a resource that is required by the Blocked-Process

**Blocked-Process**
This is the process(SP, query etc) that is blocked and is waiting on a a resource that is in use by the Blocking-Process.

**waitresource**
This details the resource that the process is waiting on. Taking your example of 
waitresource="OBJECT: 99:774293818:0 "

The 99 refers to the Database ID of your data and the 774293818 refers to the table. Using the ID 774293818 and systables you should be able to find the table that is causing the blocking.

I would also set up an Extended Events Trace to capture the parameters of the offending blocking process and review the execution plans.

A good starting point is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224453

Comment: Hello, unsurprisingly 774293818 table is the SP_ScheduleEvent table. I'm reading through that kb page now to set up Extended Events Trace. Will let you know.

Comment: Here is the execution plan of the update: http://pastie.org/10241403

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the db itself, you can run your application and take a look in the running requests (sys.dm_exec_request). There you'll find what query currently runs. You can also take a look at sys.dm_tran_locks which will give you a good overview of the requested locks on which ressource.

Another idea is to run a profiler using the tsql replay template on the database table and go throw the results. This would help you, I think.

If you need further information. Pls let me know.

Comment: I would recommend **NOT** running profiler in PROD. A server side trace or XEvents would be a much better choice. Also, your answer does not **really** provide answer to OP's question, since the blocked process report already has lock information in it.

Comment: Well not in prod, but normally you have an test instance as well. But you can capture workload using profiler on the prod server and rerun it on the test system. Well I would like to comment on the OP's question. But due to the bad reputation system in stackexchange, I won't be able to comment unless I have a reputation of 50.

Comment: `But you can capture workload using profiler on the prod server and rerun it on the test system.` NO, as I said, a [server side trace or XEvent is much lighter](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/08/01/trace-profiler-test.aspx).

Comment: Yes but you don't have to configure it manually. Normally you configure it using profiler. Configure it to write it to a table or file. Start it, pause it. Close profiler and start it using standard sql. Therefore no results were send to your client.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. I don't understand why any of the suggestions in the comments / answer are helpful. I already know what query is causing the blocking right? So I don't need to do any further trace? Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Because you don't know why they are blocking/deadlocking each other?

Comment: Ok, I'm running the tsql replay template now on the database, what is it that I'm looking out for, do I have to wait for the blocked process report to happen and then marry up the times of the event?

Comment: Normally, yes. You can then compare which operations run and what part of the operation could cause the block.

Comment: Hello, I have done this. The operations which causes the blocking is the UPDATE that I originally show in my question. You can see the execution plan for this UPDATE in my comments for the first Answer by @armitage